# How did Kirito regrow his hand in episode 10?

Tags: sword-art-online

In episode 10 of Sword Art Online, Kirito was attacked by Kuradeel. Kirito's hand was cut off by Kuradeel while saving Asuna.
Later in this episode, Kirito was shown to have both of his hands undamaged.

How could have Kirito regrown his severed hand?

Answer (score 5):

The explanation you are looking for can be found at the very end of Chapter 15 of the LN, after Kuradeel was killed by Kirito:

> I pulled Asuna in closer with the left arm that had the body part loss status imposed on it for three minutes.

This explains why he has his missing hand back later in the episode, probably even before reentering the town.

Answer (score 2):

Sword Art Online is a video game. Because it is a video game, there are areas you can regain lost health. Traditionally, entering an Inn or Home automatically heals all damage and status effects, and "maiming" is a status effect.

If Kayaba Akihiko was feeling generous, he could have made it so entering any town instantly heals you too.